# What is this headlight adapter called?

Tags: jeep, headlight, socket

A really simple question.   I have Jeep Compass 2012 and it has this adapter for the main headlights.   I assume it's an original OEM part although happy to be corrected.

Either way, what is it actually called, I have no idea abut the names of these sockets and so can't even begin to search online in order to replace.

It would be great to know the names of the two socket types on each end of the device.

[image]

Comment: Your image is the same one online which states it is the daytime running headlight bulb holder adapter

Comment: Yes I've seen that but its a very generic description. I want to know the names of the two socket types on each end of the device.

Comment: There should be a part number on it, search for that and you'll find the name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just a bulb holder that will likely be unique to that vehicle manufacturer.

Part Number appears to be - 68191950AA

Example [seller](https://www.mymoparparts.com/oem-parts/mopar-park-and-turn-signal-socket-right-68191950aa) of 68191950AA

Looks like there are plenty on ebay too.